# MVC map Viewmodels to domain models

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am struggling to figure out how to map my viewModels to domain models for to the Index, Edit, Details and Delete Action Result in the controller.

I figured out how to do the Create Action Result one with the help of Stephen, but for the other four views I am clueless. I researched and could not come up with anything that helped me. In a nutshell, I am building a web form (parent) that will eventually have the ability to add/remove rows (child). I hardcoded the children but eventually I will have some type of js function to do this.

I learned yesterday, that it might be a good idea to use one viewModels per view. In this case it would be five viewModels. For the sake of this project lets assume I will use all the properties in my mapping.

Domain Models:

```
public class Parent
{

    public int ParentID { get; set; }

    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Child> Childs { get; set; }

}

public class Child
{
    public int ChildID { get; set; }
    public int ParentID { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string DOB { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }

    public virtual Parent Parent { get; set; }
}
```

View Models:

```
public class ParentsEditVM
{

    public ParentsEditVM()
    {

    }


    public int ParentID { get; set; }

    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public IList<ChildVM> Children { get; set; }

}


public ParentsCreateVM()
    {
        Children = new List<ChildVM>()
            {
                new ChildVM(){Name="1", DOB="1", Address="1"},
                new ChildVM(){Name="2", DOB="2", Address="0"},
                new ChildVM(){Name="3", DOB="3", Address="3"},                    
            };

    }


    public int ParentID { get; set; }

    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public IList<ChildVM> Children { get; set; }

}

 public class ChildVM
{
    public int ChildID { get; set; }
    public int ParentID { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string DOB { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
 public class ParentsController : Controller
{
    private OnlineFormsContext db = new OnlineFormsContext();

    // GET: Parents
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(db.Parents.ToList());
    }

    // GET: Parents/Details/5
    public ActionResult Details(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
        Parent parent = db.Parents.Find(id);
        if (parent == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        return View(parent);
    }

    // GET: Parents/Create
    public ActionResult Create()
    {

        return View(new ParentsCreateVM());

    }

    // POST: Parents/Create
    // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
    // more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create(ParentsCreateVM viewModel)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {

            var parent = new Parent()
            {
                FirstName = viewModel.FirstName,
                LastName = viewModel.LastName
            };

            db.Parents.Add(parent);

            foreach (ChildVM item in viewModel.Children)
            {

                var child = new Child()
                {
                    Name = item.Name,
                    DOB = item.DOB,
                    Address = item.Address
                };
                db.Childs.Add(child);
            }

            //Parent parent = new Parent();              
            //var employee = AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<Parent, ParentVM>(parent);                        

            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View(viewModel);
    }

    // GET: Parents/Edit/5
    public ActionResult Edit(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
        Parent parent = db.Parents.Find(id);
        if (parent == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }


        // http://forums.asp.net/t/1900785.aspx?Editing+one+to+many+relationships+MVC+4+EF
        //var model = new ParentsEditVM(parent);
        //return View(model);
        return View(new ParentsEditVM());
        //return View(parent);
    }

    // POST: Parents/Edit/5
    // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
    // more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include = "ParentID,FirstName,LastName")] Parent parent)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Entry(parent).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        return View(parent);
    }

    // GET: Parents/Delete/5
    public ActionResult Delete(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
        Parent parent = db.Parents.Find(id);
        if (parent == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        return View(parent);
    }

    // POST: Parents/Delete/5
    [HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult DeleteConfirmed(int id)
    {
        Parent parent = db.Parents.Find(id);
        db.Parents.Remove(parent);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing)
        {
            db.Dispose();
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you wanting to know how to map the domain model to the view model when you are editing an existing parent? (currently you just passing `new ParentsEditVM()` so its not populated)

Comment: Yes and I also want to do it for the index, details and delete action. I am guessing the mapping will be the same for Index and details (no post back) and the same mapping for edit and Delete or close. I know what I have so far does not make sense. I could not figure out how to do it.

Comment: You just need to do it as you have done for the `Create()` POST method, but in reverse (I'll post an answer shortly, but you could also consider using tools such as [automapper](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper) which makes it easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To map your domain model to the view model in the edit method

```
Parent p = db.Parents.Find(id);

ParentsEditVM model = new ParentsEditVM()
{
  ParentID = p.ParentID,
  FirstName =p.FirstName,
  LastName = p.LastName,
  Children = p.Childs.Select(c => new ChildVM()
  {
    ChildID = c.ChildID,
    Name = c.Name,
    ... etc
  }).ToList(),
};
....
return View(model);
```

Note. I don't think `ChildVM` really needs to include property `ParentID` (when you post back you already know the `ParentID` from `ParentsEditVM`. Also you may be over complicating this with separate create and edit view models if the only difference is the fact that in Create, `ParentID` will be null and in `Edit`, it will have a value. And is it necessary to have a `GET` method for delete. Typically you might have a Delete button/link on either the `Index` or `Details` view (may or may not be displayed based on the users permissions) which could be a `form` element that just posts back the `ID` of the `Parent` to the `Delete()` method

Comment: Ok, I have so many questions. 1) this is for the Edit (Post) correct? what about the Edit (get) one? 2) The constructors are the difference in the ParentsCreateVM and ParentsEditVM, which brings me to the question, Do I even need a constructor for the ParentsEditVM. 3) What about Index, Details and Delete action result, do I even need to have viewsmodel for those?

Comment: I think your first line as an error, it should be ParentsEditVM model = db.Parents.Find(id).Select(p => new ParentsEditVM()   ... correct?

Comment: (1) No, that was for the `Edit()` GET. You getting the domain model from the database (`db.Parents.Find(id)`) and mapping its properties to `ParentsEditVM` (`.Select(p => new ParentsEditVM() {...`). (2) No, you do not need constructors for view models. Their properties should be assigned in the controller (any in any case, only a parameter-less constructor is used by the `DefaultModelBinder` on post back). (3) Since `Index` and `Detail` wont have any controls to post back, a separate view model is not really necessary. As for the `Delete`, see last part of my answer.

Comment: ok, so for the Edit() Post will that be like the logic for the Create() Post? Also, no biggy but I think you put a + instead of = in your answer.

Comment: Exactly (in the POST method(s) you need to map from the view model to the domain model).  Note also for future questions try and address just one issue at a time, and keep the code to the minimum (you have so much here its hard to digest)

Comment: Yeah but your good, you can handle it! :-) OK, I will do that in the future. I will work on this tomorrow night. It is getting late here. I hope you will be online you are extremely helpful. Thanks so much.

Comment: OK, I am getting an error message: Namespace.Models.Parent' does not contain a definition for 'Select' and no extension method 'Select' accepting a first argument of type... The error is on the first select. Also, I believe there was a typo in your code the parenthesis right after .. etc is suppose to be }),

Comment: OK. (db.Parents.Find(id) return a single object not a collection). Give new a few minutes and I'll update.

Comment: Dang it, I think we are almost there. Another error message: Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Namespace.ViewModels.ChildVM>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IList<Namespace.ViewModels.ChildVM>'  I think it needs a (cast).  A little out of my league

Comment: Awesome, Thanks so much for all your patience, tips, and help. I have learned a lot and got a long way to go. :-(